# How do I add additional external Git remotes on internal remote?

Tags: git

While developing some patches on projects with an upstream Git repository I'm currently doing the following.

```
superproject/submodules/actualproject

^ parent repo           ^ Git submodule
```

`actualproject` has two remotes:

- `vendor` being the "upstream" remote.
- `myname` being my own "internal" remote repository.

Works fine this way, but as soon as another person (colleague) clones my tree (either using the superproject via submodules or just one of the submodules on its own), he'll have:

- remote `origin` being my repository.
- remote `vendor` isn't present.

What's the best way to have at least the `vendor` remote configured automatically for the others cloning? Can I use the powers of submodules here? Eg. `submodule init` already sets a remote - can I set a second?

Or, is this a completely wrong approach from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague should `git clone <URL to 'vendor' repo>` instead of using your own repo. That way he'll get that remote (it'll be called "origin" at first because that's a git default, but he could change it if he wanted to).

**Edit**: To change the submodule remote he gets when he clones the super-project, you'll have to edit your .gitmodules file to point to 'vendor' instead of 'myname'  ;)

Comment: Now reading your answer I realized my question wasn't exactly narrowed down very well and I've oversimplified things. I guess it's fine concerning the situation described in my question. I might re-ask it later once I am more confident about how to put this into the right words (rather than changing the question too much to invalidate your answer). Thanks for this anyway. :)

Comment: To answer the question that you might be wondering about: No, Git can't save other remotes in a remote, and can't create another upstream remote besides origin. But you could maintain cloning/creation/update scripts for your projects in a separate repository, which all your colleagues should use when cloning your project(s) :)

Answer (score -1):

you can add another remote

```
git remote add backup user@server:/path/to/git/test.git
git push backup master
```

[www.hostatic.ro/2011/09/29/pushing-to-two-git-remote-origins-from-one-repository/](http://www.hostatic.ro/2011/09/29/pushing-to-two-git-remote-origins-from-one-repository/) , [andersonleeb.com/blog/changing-git-remote-origin](http://andersonleeb.com/blog/changing-git-remote-origin)

EDIT : I missed the point in you question but i think Git can't save other remotes in a remote without scripts

Comment: I know how to add git remotes and how to push. That's not what my question is about. Please re-read.